# What vehicle does this master cylinder and booster go too

Tags: brakes, vehicle-identification, master-cylinder, brake-booster

This is a pic of my old master and booster off my 1966 chevy c10. It is not correct to vehicle. I'm trying to figure out what make and model vehicle this is for.  Any help would be much appreciated.                                                            The only thing I see on booster is this sticker the # on it is 3150   on the master there is ADX and the letter S or number 2 on bottom of it. The inside of masters lid has the numbers 52034 and Y.S  3.   That's all I can see.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCxXI.jpg]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, welcome! If you can take some pictures with numbers or other identifying marks that would be ***very*** helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As Kyle said ...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I was about to do the pic edit too. Lol.

Comment: Safe bet the truck did not originally have power brakes and someone did an upgrade.

Comment: As @agentp a later fit due to an upgrade - best bet go to a brake specialist and they will be able to tell you. That's how I got the "best" bits to upgrade my brakes - have the dimensions and check what fits...

Comment: Google came up with something that may narrow it down: [http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/shop_parts/brake_booster/chevy/c10.html]
The list is too long to paste in, but click the "see more" under "Fits the following Chevrolet C10 Years" . 

Shortened version here:
"78-80 Big Ten
78-80 Cheyenne
78-80 Custom Deluxe
78-80 Scottsdale
78-80 Silverado"

Silverado might be reasonably easy to find?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't been able to find anything good. Then best advice I can give is these 2 options:

1. Find what is "factory stock" for the '66 C10, and work your way backward from there. That's not a very viable method I think because the best you're gonna get is a group of possible vehicles.
2. Take it to a brake specialist and see if they can tell you. They probably won't be able to be more specific though, because many parts go one multiple models/years. They probably won't be able to tell you exactly which model year it can off of originally, but who knows!? Maybe they will!

---

The best guess I could give is that it's from a GM. It could be a replacement part made in a later year. The sticker looks like an 1980s kinda thing at the earliest. It has a barcode on it and I don't believe those even existed in the '60s. Could be newer too though.

I know this doesn't really give an exact answer, so if someone can come up with better information, I'm okay with that. But it's the best I've been able to put together.

Part of the problem is that (I think) there was a lot less serial number matching and all that back in those days, so it may be impossible to pull an accurate model year. I can say with ~95% certainty that if it was in another vehicle first, it was on a GM vehicle.